# How to effectively swap OpenCL memory buffers?

Tags: buffer, opencl, swap

Exactly as the title suggests I am looking for how to effectively swap two OpenCL buffers. My kernel uses two gloabl buffers, one as input and one as output. However, I invoke my kernel in a for loop with the same NDRange, each time setting the kernel arguments, enqueueing the kernel, and swapping the buffers because the previous output buffer will be the input buffer seed for the next iteration.

What is the appropriate way here, to swap these two buffers? I imagine that copying the buffer back to the host to one of the already malloc'd arrays and copying it into the next input buffer using `clEnqueueWriteBuffer()` and `clEnqueueReadBuffer()` is an inefficient way to go. Otherwise I am just using a temporary `cl_mem` variable to do my swapping.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to, just set the right kernel args using `clSetKernelArg` before enqueuing your kernel a second time (using `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel`). The buffers will stay on the device, nothing will be copied back to the host.

Your buffer has to be created with `CL_MEM_READ_WRITE` in this case of course.

Comment: Well I thought about that. But it seems I would have to alternate the input and output kernel args every iteration no?

Comment: Yes - you will. Swap and set them on each iteration. This is ping-ponging (http://www.mathematik.uni-dortmund.de/~goeddeke/gpgpu/tutorial.html#feedback2)

Comment: Ok well I certainly thought about that. But sorry if I didnt make it clear in my question. "Second time" implies two times. Not millions. Otherwise what is the point of massive parallelism. Thanks to you both.

Comment: You can use `std::swap(bufferA, bufferB);` before the call to `setArg` to avoid having to use separate code for even and odd iterations.

Answer (score 4):

As the previous answer: **No, you don't need to swap buffers at all.**

However, I don't agree with the proposed answer. The function `clSetKernelArg()` is **not thread safe**, and is not designed to be called in the operation loop.

The proper solution is to create 2 kernels created with the same program and source. This approach is more aligned with the OpenCL programming philosophy "One kernel for one task". Having many kernels with the same code but different arguments is the way to go.

The first kernel will have:

```
kernel1 = clCreateKernel(program, "mykernel", NULL);
clSetKernelArg(kernel1, 0, &buff1);
clSetKernelArg(kernel1, 1, &buff2);
```

And the other one will be:

```
kernel2 = clCreateKernel(program, "mykernel", NULL);
clSetKernelArg(kernel2, 0, &buff2);
clSetKernelArg(kernel2, 1, &buff1);
```

This way, you don't need to stop the execution each iteration. You can simply run:

```
for(int it=0; it<iter; it++){
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(it%2 ? kernel1 : kernel2, ....);
}
clFinish(command);
```

This approach will be surely better than changing the kernel args, more efficient, less API calls. Additionally on some systems, `clSetKernelArgs()` may be a blocking call, due to poor API implementations. So it is better to avoid them as much as possible.

Comment: while I agree that, clSetKernelArg is not thread safe, your statement about "will not allow you to run the next iteration without finishing the previous" is not correct, once you call clEnqueueNDRangeKernel all parameters are copied, so you can immediately set whatever you want, right after enqueuing kernel.

Comment: I updated my answer. You are right, 99% of the available platforms are not blocking, only some old drivers, or badly implemented ones are blocking on `clSetKernelArgs()`