# Swap memory buffers effectively in OpenCL: implementation

Tags: opencl

I have faced the same problem as here: [How to effectively swap OpenCL memory buffers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041081/how-to-effectively-swap-opencl-memory-buffers). My first implementation was the same as has been described in the question, at each cycle it writes/reads memory buffers to/from the device. As pointed out this introduces useless read/write buffer overhead. The code (with memory overhead) below works fine:

```
//THIS WORKS!!!

f0_mem = clCreateBuffer(
        context,
        CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, 
        sizeof (int)*(capacity + 1), 
        NULL, 
        &err);

f1_mem = (..."the same as above"...);
m_d_mem = clCreateBuffer(..., CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, sizeof (int)*capacity,...);

for (int k = 0; k < numelem; k++) {

    sumK = sumK - weight[k];
    cmax = 0;
    cmax = max(capacity - sumK, weight[k]);
    total_elements = (size_t) (capacity - cmax + 1);

    if (k % 2 == 0) {

        //clEnqueueWriteBuffer of cl_mem buffers
        writeBufferToDevice(f0_mem, f1_mem, f0, f1);
        setKernelArgs(f0_mem, f1_mem, weight[k], value[k], (int) total_elements);

    } else {

        //clEnqueueWriteBuffer of cl_mem buffers
        writeBufferToDevice(f1_mem, f0_mem, f1, f0);
        setKernelArgs(f1_mem, f0_mem, weight[k], value[k], (int) total_elements);

    }

    err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, global_work_items, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

    //clEnqueueReadBuffer of cl_mem buffers
    readBufferFromDevice(f0_mem, f1_mem, m_d_mem, f0, f1, m_d);

    memcpy(M + k*capacity, m_d, sizeof (int)*capacity);
}
```

**EDIT:** My kernel:

```
void kernel knapsack(global int *input_f, global int *output_f, global int *m_d,  int cmax, int weightk, int pk, int maxelem){

int c = get_global_id(0)+cmax;

if(get_global_id(0) < maxelem){

    if(input_f[c] < input_f[c - weightk] + pk){
        output_f[c] = input_f[c - weightk] + pk;
        m_d[c-1] = 1;
    } 
    else{
    output_f[c] = input_f[c];

    }   
  }    
}
```

After I have tried to implement the two suggested solutions:

1. simply swapping setKernelArgs(...)
2. create two kernels

For the first one this my code:

```
//ARGUMENTS SWAP

f0_mem = ...
f1_mem = ...
m_d_mem = ...

//clEnqueueWriteBuffer occurs hear
writeBufferToDevice( (cl_mem&) f0_mem, (cl_mem&) f1_mem, (cl_mem&) m_d_mem, (int*) f0, (int*) f1, (int*) m_d);

for (int k = 0; k < numelem; k++) {

    /*
       The same code block
    */

    if (k % 2 == 0) {

        setKernelArgs(f0_mem, f1_mem, weight[k], value[k], (int) total_elements);

    } else {

        setKernelArgs(f1_mem, f0_mem, weight[k], value[k], (int) total_elements);

    }

    err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, global_work_items, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

    err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, m_d_mem, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof (int)*capacity, m_d, 0, NULL, NULL);                  

    memcpy(M + k*capacity, m_d, sizeof (int)*capacity);

}
```

The second solution is implemented in this way:

```
//TWO KERNELS

f0_mem = ...
f1_mem = ...
m_d_mem = ...

//clEnqueueWriteBuffer occurs hear
writeBufferToDevice( (cl_mem&) f0_mem, (cl_mem&) f1_mem, (cl_mem&) m_d_mem, (int*) f0, (int*) f1, (int*) m_d);

for (int k = 0; k < numelem; k++) {

    /*
       The same code block
    */

    if (k % 2 == 0) {

        setKernelArgs(f0_mem, f1_mem, weight[k], value[k], (int) total_elements);
        clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel0, 1, NULL, global_work_items, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

    } else {

        setKernelArgs(kernel1, f1_mem, f0_mem, weight[k], value[k], (int) total_elements);
        clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel1, 1, NULL, global_work_items, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

    }

    clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, m_d_mem, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof (int)*capacity, m_d, 0, NULL, NULL);                  

    memcpy(M + k*capacity, m_d, sizeof (int)*capacity);

}
```

Neither of the two solutions work for me (it seems to me, no swapping occur at all!), what am I doing wrong?

Sub-question: in the last two solutions, is it possible to have memory buffers filled with zeroes without using  writeBufferToDevice( f0_mem, f1_mem, m_d_mem...) before the for cycle?

***This work is based on this article***:

- [Solving knapsack problems on GPU by V. Boyera, D. El Baza,  M. Elkihel](https://cel.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01152223/document)
- related work: [Accelerating the knapsack problem on GPUs by Bharath Suri](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:439054/FULLTEXT01.pdf)

Comment: You are clearly messing with the buffer order somewhere. I don see any problem in your CL code. BTW, for the second case, you dont need the setKernelArgs in the loop. That is the reason to have 2 kernels, otherwise just go for the first case.

Comment: Thanks for setKernelArgs note, you are right about that. What do you mean messing with buffers, they don't overlap during the kernel computation , as they are separated ( at each iteration one buffer is used as input and another as output), and also I have thread control to prevent race conditions. Also the kernel has been tested the kernel on the intel opencl sdk, and haven't experienced any problems. I can't figure out the issue with buffers, please tell me more precisely what on your opinion could cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Both attempted solutions looks correct to me but there may be some dependencies between each iteration - you would have to post your kernel to check.
It works fine in your solution probably because you are writing and reading each iteration which works slower so it's enough time to synchronize itself. 
You can try to add `clFinish(command);` after each OpenCL API call to see if that makes a difference.

Apart from that there is 3rd solution you could try: **swapping pointers in the kernel**. You will need to move your loop from CPU to GPU.

```
inline void swap_pointers(__global double **A, __global double **B)
{
    __global double *tmp = *A;
    *A = *B;
    *B = tmp;
}

__kernel void my_kernel(
__global double *pA,
__global double *pB,
...
)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < numelem; k++) 
    {

        // some stuff here

        swap_pointers(&pA, &pB);
        barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE | CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    }
}
```

Then read everything in one go on the host (m_d_mem must be big enough to store data from all iterations):

```
clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, m_d_mem, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof (int)*capacity*numelem, m_d, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Unfortunately clFinish(command_queue) doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Your solution is fine, but not feasible for my project. I have to use big chunks of  buffers therefore they wouldn't fit into the device memory or the transfers would be to long.

Comment: @NicoMkhatvari Can you post minimal compilable version reproducing the problem?

Comment: [here you can find it](https://github.com/nico-mkhatvari/OpenCL/blob/ShortCode/Knapsack%20OpenCL/knapsack_main.cpp). Worth to note: the decision matrix and chosen items printouts are wrong in "swapping buffers" case but it's correct in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** 
At each cycle after copying m_d to M, the m_d should be reseted and written back to m_d_mem buffer object with Knapsack::writeBuffer_m_d_ToDevice()

```
 ksack.readBuffer_m_d_FromDevice();            
 memcpy(M + k*capacity, m_d, sizeof (int)*capacity);
 ksack.writeBuffer_m_d_ToDevice();//resets m_d_mem
```